# django acces model field by string

Tags: django, string, model, field

I was wondering if it is possible to acces a field in a djangomodel from a string. Letme give you an example:

class:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town, unique=True)

    coin = models.IntegerField()
    wood = models.IntegerField()
    iron = models.IntegerField()
    grain = models.IntegerField()
    stone = models.IntegerField()
```

Now somewhere in my other code, i would like to acces a field like this

```
example="coin"
resources = Resource.objects.get(town="some town"):
resources.example
```

I know the resources.example doesnt work, i was wondering if there was some way to achieve that?

With kind regards,
Hans de Jong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access an attribute of any object in python by name using the [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function

```
example="coin"
resources = Resource.objects.get(town="some town"):
getattr(resources, example)
```